# Как сделать, чтобы резиновая шапка не срезалась при маленьком расширении

Tags: html

Здравствуйте! Столкнулась с такой проблемой: делаю сайт с фиксированным логотипом(1000px) и резиновой шапкой, при просмотре на мониторах с большим расширением все отлично, а при небольших расширениях шапка срезается и логотип выходит за ее пределы. В инете нашла совет поставить min-width 1000px, пробовала, шапка так же срезается. Что еще можно сделать?

Comment: > логотип 1000px

Лебедева на вас нет...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Варианты без масштабирования:

1. Сделать логотип фоном шапки.
2. Использовать для шапки [overflow:hidden](http://htmlbook.ru/css/overflow)

Если блок будет меньше изображения, то часть изображения будет не видна. Поэтому для блока с логотипом выставляем min-width или (что не очень хорошо, конечно) добавляем в блок прозрачный однопиксельный gif, растянутый на нужную длину (1000px).

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, можно с помощью JS вычислять ширину просматриваемой области и задавать размер для логотипа соответственно ей. Только это сработает, если логотип ваш добавлен на страницу, как элемент **img**, а не как бэкграунд блока. Или же, в зависимости от размера окна, использовать уменьшенную или увеличенную копию логотипа.

Набросал простой пример - http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/S6ePk/1/